# What is your way to do GAE Apps using Clojure?

Tags: google-app-engine, clojure, compojure

I want to develop apps on GAE using Clojure with Compojure, using either Eclipse or Idea, emacs is not a bad idea :P

So which are the best ways to do this? I don't think that I want to use leiningen because I believe that maven can be very strong if you pass the learning curve - I read this blog http://compojureongae.posterous.com/tag/googleappengine which 'till now is one of the best source of information.

If you will have to do this, what will be your approach? Or what will you recommend me?

Is this plugin -> http://code.google.com/p/maven-gae-plugin/ ok? because if I use that plugin I can include in the pom.xml the clojure.jar and basically I'm ready to go, right? Is something similar for IntelliJ IDEA?

Any other suggestions?
And which is your way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There recently was an announcement on the Clojure mailing list of a library called appengine-magic which tries to abstract away the boilerplate related to GAE:

http://github.com/gcv/appengine-magic

http://osdir.com/ml/clojure/2010-09/msg00942.html

Answer (score 3):

Just a some links. I think if you really want that combination you have to do some stoff your self but this should help.

- Compojure on GAE http://compojureongae.posterous.com/
- Clojure on GAE http://www.hackers-with-attitude.com/

Comment: the second url seems interesting, the first one is already mentioned by me :)